# Plotting Points on OSM from MongoDB

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, template-engine

The data stored in my Database "video" of "shows" collection in mongodb is as [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQ7tF.jpg). It has 3 feilds as dose_rate, x, y.

My code for "app.js" is as follows :

```
var express=require('express');
var MongoClient=require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var engines=require('consolidate');
var assert=require('assert');
var app=express();

app.engine('html',engines.nunjucks);
app.set('view engine','html');
app.set('views',__dirname+ '/views');

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/video',function(err,db){
assert.equal(null,err);
console.log("successfully connect to the MongoDB server");
app.get('/',function(req,res){
    db.collection('shows').find({}).toArray(function(err,docs){
        res.render('shows',{'shows':docs});
        });
      });
    });
 });

app.listen(4596,function(req,res){
console.log("connect to the port 4596");
});
```

the below code is for "shows.html" :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>

<head>
<title>Plotting points</title>
</head>

<body>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
{%for show in shows%}
<li>{{show.dose_rate}}</li>
<li> {{show.x}}</li>
<li>{{show.y}}</li>
{%endfor%}
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

on running the code of "app.js" and on opening "shows.html" from browser on localhost, the output is that all points (i.e dose_rate, x, y) of my "shows" collection in "video" database is displayed  on HTML page as [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6LZTp.png).

Now i have code for plotting single point (77.5,18.1025)on OSM *INDEPENDENTLY* as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html> 
<head>
<title>OpenLayers Simplest Example</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="Map" style="height:600px"></div>
<script src="/home/padmesh/mean/osm sample/OpenLayers.js"></script>
<script>
var lat            = 77.5;
var lon            = 18.1025;
var zoom           = 10;

var fromProjection = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"); //Transform from WGS 1984
var toProjection   = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"); //to Spherical Mercator Projection
var position       = new OpenLayers.LonLat(lat,lon).transform( fromProjection, toProjection);

map = new OpenLayers.Map("Map");
var mapnik         = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM();
map.addLayer(mapnik);

var markers = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers( "Markers" );
map.addLayer(markers);
markers.addMarker(new OpenLayers.Marker(position));

map.setCenter(position, zoom);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**I want to plot all my points stored in my collection "shows" as "x" and "y" from that db on OSM map, one by one, at once. I tried finding all reference to this problem but failed to find one. Please help me in doing so as i am new to OSM and nodejs or post any reference which i can read or tag someone who can help. THANK YOU IN ADVANCE**

Comment: "It is not working" Is not really specific... Add your code and provide more details to understand your problem. As it is right now your question is too broad, unclear and off-topic as you are asking for debugging-help without code, error message details.

Comment: Please see [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for details.

Comment: @geisterfurz007 for replying. I have edited my question for better understanding. please suggest me if any other changes are required.

Comment: @KevinAdistambha  thank you too for replying. please tag any relevant person who can help me to this problem.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to display the contents of your database using OpenStreetMap. Since this is a specific OpenStreetMap use case, I suggest asking in https://help.openstreetmap.org/ instead. As an aside, the MongoDB+express code seems to be working correctly.

Comment: Also, you're attempting to combine two unrelated methods. The express template will output the contents of the database in HTML format, while the example you posted (which I believe was copied verbatim from http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OpenLayers_Simple_Example) displays only a single point that was defined in Javascript. I suggest looking for a method in OSM to display multiple points and start from there.

Comment: thank you for suggesting me to take help from OSM forum. ill do follow that. The example which i mentioned in my question plots a point on the Map and i want to plot stream of points from the mongodb and to plot those series of point(that is in my db),i need to bring them to HTML  individually (and NOT as batch of points). @kevinAdistambha how to i do that? get those points individually till HTML? my shows.html with app.js running brings "BATCH" of points and displays them at a time. what i want is that it should get displayed individually independently. is that possible?

Comment: also @KevinAdistamba it will be okay for me even if those points from mongodb get into Array. so that i manipulate them as i want. is it possible? if yes you can help me by posting any reference you have